# How can I make Firefox change google search result links to direct links to what they say they are?

Tags: firefox, google-search

I don't know if anyone else even has this problem, or has noticed, but all of my Google search result links (when signed in) look like they're going to the URL listed below the link - stackoverflow.com/ for example, but if you right click the link and copy, the resulting paste will produce this instead:

`http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&ei=ANNMStDNE52etwe43tGqBA&usg=AFQjCNERidL9Hb6OvGW93_Y6MRj3aTdMVA&sig2=EiL3mfVwGXZZ3HRKWN5srw`

It's an infuriating PITA when all I'm looking to do is get a link to something.  I search, then copy the link - that on mouseover looks like the actual result - but the link I get is that monster above.

Is there some obscure Google option to turn this off? Or a grease monkey script to rewrite the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [CustomizeGoogle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/743)? Or, entering google via

```
http://www.google.com/ig?pws=0
```

(personalized web search off) should also work. I'm sure there are other similar plugins and URLs that can offer similar help.

Comment: This works if you use the option (under Web) "Remove click tracking"

Comment: greasemonkey script at http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/57679

Comment: Now at http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/57679

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the target URL in the status bar, then its in there, probably within an onMouseMove event in the anchor tag of the result.  If you're looking to scrape google, then use that instead.